# BitmapImage to byte[] Windows 8 metro (WinRT)

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I want to convert `BitmapImage` to byte[] in windows 8 application. I know how to do it using windows sdk but can't seem to get it working for WinRT sdk.

One or two posts are suggesting that I should use `WritableBitmap` to achieve that but there are no clear examples.

[Conversion of BitmapImage to Byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732807/conversion-of-bitmapimage-to-byte-array) (Windows)

following is the best I found but still too vague for me

[WinRT Loading an Image into a Byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181046/winrt-loading-an-image-into-a-byte-array)

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: How *isn't* this a duplicate of the first question that you linked to?

Comment: it's not since first question doesn't cover Windows-RT which is different from regular windows sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the WriteableBitmapEx project here - http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/  It is discussed here - [WinRT Loading an Image into a Byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181046/winrt-loading-an-image-into-a-byte-array)... from the answer...

> Basically you need to load the image into a WriteableBitmap, then
>   access its pixel buffer by calling PixelBuffer.AsStream().

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

- [BitmapDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226192)
- [PixelDataProvider.DetachPixelData()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.pixeldataprovider.detachpixeldata)

And then you have a byte array of BitmapImage!

See this how to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709939.aspx