# Convert BitmapImage to byte[] array in Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, arrays, bitmapimage

There are a few samples to do this but they are for Windows Phone 8.0 or 8.1 Silverlight.

But how can you do this for Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime?

Comment: There http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732807/conversion-of-bitmapimage-to-byte-array are some considerations about it.

Comment: @marcinax did you read the title? Or what I posted? I know there are 100 samples and questions to do this... That link you posted is for Windows Phone """7"""!!!!

Comment: So another link for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963508/bitmapimage-to-byte-windows-8-metro-winrt. It's for WinRT. Use search.

Comment: @marcinax doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot extract the pixels from a Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.[BitmapImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

The most general solution is to use a WriteableBitmap instead of a BitmapImage. These classes are both [BitmapSources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx) and can be used almost interchangeably. The [WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) provides access to its pixel data via its [PixelBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer.aspx) property:

```
byte[] pixelArray = myWriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer.ToArray(); // convert to Array
Stream pixelStream = wb.PixelBuffer.AsStream();  // convert to stream
```

Otherwise you will need to acquire the pixels from wherever the BitmapImage got them from. Depending on how the BitmapImage was initialized you may be able to find its origin from its [UriSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.urisource.aspx) property. The [WinRT Xaml Toolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit) has an [extension method FromBitmapImage](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.UWP/Imaging/WriteableBitmapFromBitmapImageExtension.cs) to create a WriteableBitmap from an BitmapImage based on its UriSource.

An ugly option would be to render the BitmapImage into an Image, create a [RenderTargetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) based on the Image and then get its Pixels with RenderTargetBitmap.[CopyPixelsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.getpixelsasync.aspx)()

Comment: This is how I get and show the image: StorageFile storageFile = args.Files[0];
                var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
                var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);

                var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

Comment: I saw the very same code snippet now a few times in various places and wondered whether the pixel stream needs disposing?

Comment: Had to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;` to access the `AsStream()` extension method.

Answer (score -1):

Tried this?

```
private byte[] ConvertToBytes(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    byte[] data = null;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);
        wBitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, wBitmap.PixelWidth, wBitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        data = stream.GetBuffer();
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: This won't work for a Windows Phone Runtime app since Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap doesn't have a constructor which takes a BitmapImage.

Comment: Nope, this ain't UWP code either. UWP _also_ does not have such a constructor.