# BitmapImage pixel array in a Universal Windows App with C#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, imaging

I am programming a Universal Windows App in C# and have ran into a point in my code where I wish to get a pixel array out of a *BitmapImage* object.

Although one can do this easily with **BitmapImage.CopyPixels()** if one is using the **System.Windows.Media.Imaging** namespace, I found the namespace was unavailable for Windows Universal Apps. Instead I used the **Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging** namespace to import my image, which does not have the **BitmapImage.CopyPixels( )** method.

Fortunately, I can create a *BitmapDecoder* object with the  **Windows.Graphics.Imaging** namespace, which does allow me to extract the pixel information using **BitmapDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync( )** function. Unfortunately I cannot find a way too convert a *BitmapImage* to a *BitmapDecoder*.

Is there a way to do this, or am I going about fetching a pixel array from a *BitmapImage* object the complete wrong way? Any suggestions would help!

Comment: Create a temp file in local storage.<br/> 
For each image whose pixel you need write it into that temp file.
Now you can read it and use BitmapDecoder to get your pixels.
You can refer [this tutorial](http://www.contentmaster.com/winrt/accessing-image-pixel-data-in-a-c-windows-store-app/)

Comment: You may take a look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34191801/2681948).

Comment: Thanks for the help.