# Windows 8 metro apps convert existing image to byte[]

Tags: c#

I am trying to save an existing image (inside a button in my app) to byte[] then save it to SQLite database. I know how to use `FileOpenPicker` to load and convert to `IRandomAccessStream`, and I know how to save to database but I can't figure our how to convert an existing image to byte array in metro apps/windows UI.

I have searched a lot but found mainly examples with FileOpenPicker or using memory stream which doesn't seem to work with metro apps.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Datareader` as

```
    var file = await new FileOpenPicker().PickSingleFileAsync();
    var fStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

    var reader = new DataReader(fStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
    var bytes = new byte[fStream.Size];
    await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fStream.Size);
    reader.ReadBytes(bytes);
```

Finally you can save `bytes` to database.

One more example here [Reading a StorageFile to a byte array in C#](http://amoore.katalyststudios.com/content/reading-storagefile-byte-array-c)

**Added Edit**

WinRT you will need to use http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

[WinRT Loading an Image into a Byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181046/winrt-loading-an-image-into-a-byte-array)

Quoting..

> Basically you need to load the image into a WriteableBitmap, then
>   access its pixel buffer by calling PixelBuffer.AsStream().

Comment: the image is inside a button in my app. I don't need to use FileOpenPicker. I need to convert that image to byte array.

Comment: Is it possible to share some code/xaml ? btw you can examine button's bacground property to get an bitmap image which you can convert to byte array

Comment: 'foreach (var btn in ButtonsCollection)
            {

                var bmp = btn.Image;
               //////////////////////

                // I need to convert bmp to IRandomAccessStream and I am stuck

                //////////////////////
                
                var reader = new DataReader(stream.GetInputStreamAt(0));// 
                var bytes = new byte[stream.Size];
                await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
                reader.ReadBytes(bytes);
                
            }'

Comment: Thanks Amitd but I am working with c# windows 8 Metro apps and there is no bitmapencoder frames.

Comment: Sorry my bad.. Edited my answer